# Are there downsides to always requiring mathn in a rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, math

So I have a rails application that was calculating a ranking value for baseball statistics and I had a importance formula that included an "importance" calculation that looked like this:

```
ranking_value.formula.map{|factor| factor[:importance] ? (1/factor[:importance]) : 1}.sum
```

As you might imagine, this came back and bit me later, because factor[:importance] was an integer, and I ended up an inaccurate sum - and while I had tried to be careful in other places where I remembered to cast divisors as floats - this is making me worried where else I've done this along the line, naturally expecting the division to be naturally floating point.

So, I'm thinking of requiring [mathn](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/mathn/rdoc/Math.html) in every Rails application that does calculations from here on out, just  in my Rails application.rb or as a config/initializer

Clearly there are sometimes when I might actually want integers - but it seems better to fail on the side of accuracy and force integers where I need them (e.g. doing a.div(b) where needed).

Is mathn slower? From a quick benchmark yes - but not so slow that I'd think there would be a real world issue:

```
require 'benchmark'

puts "----------------\nWithout mathn\n----------------"

n = 100000
Benchmark.bmbm do |x|
  x.report{for i in 1..n; a = 42/8; end}
  x.report{for i in 1..n; a = 42/8.to_f; end}
end

puts "----------------\nWith mathn\n----------------"
require 'mathn'
Benchmark.bmbm do |x|
  x.report{for i in 1..n; a = 42/8; end}
  x.report{for i in 1..n; a = (42/8).to_f; end}
end
```

results in:

```
± ruby test.rb
----------------
Without mathn
----------------
Rehearsal ------------------------------------
   0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.008576)
   0.020000   0.000000   0.020000 (  0.025659)
--------------------------- total: 0.030000sec

       user     system      total        real
   0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.008334)
   0.030000   0.000000   0.030000 (  0.023857)
----------------
With mathn
----------------
Rehearsal ------------------------------------
   0.030000   0.000000   0.030000 (  0.034743)
   0.050000   0.000000   0.050000 (  0.051568)
--------------------------- total: 0.080000sec

       user     system      total        real
   0.040000   0.000000   0.040000 (  0.035893)
   0.050000   0.000000   0.050000 (  0.054138)
```

Are there downsides that I'm missing? Maybe even a better way of not shooting myself in the foot over all with integer division?

(p.s. I know this question is borderline on being discussion oriented - but hopefully it's framed with enough data to lean toward some answers)

Comment: As a real-world test - I have a method that does a data rebuild - calculating scaled distributions for 71 stat categories across 700 players (so it has to walk and scale and store those arrays in a serialized field) - and updates about 4,960 rows. So maybe a typical "small scale" dataset.

with mathn: 15.870000   0.570000  16.440000 ( 18.240111)
without mathn: 15.960000   0.570000  16.530000 ( 18.420020)

I don't think "without" is faster because of mathn, probably just database variation. But it seems like a decent test.